# Tkinter: StringVar not work, is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a problem with StringVar in my code. My problem is that the variable is empty, it does not include the value of the entry. 
I have two differents methods, one works and the other does not, but are apparently identical.

This work:

```
def ventanaPrincipal():
    top = Tkinter.Tk()
    var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    L1 = Tkinter.Label(top, text="Introduzca el nombre"+"\n"+ "completo del remitente:")
    E1 = Tkinter.Entry(top,textvariable = var)
    def buscar():
        buscarPorNombreYApellidos(var.get())

    B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Buscar", command = buscar)
    L1.pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
    B1.pack(side = Tkinter.RIGHT)
    E1.pack( side = Tkinter.RIGHT)
    top.mainloop()
```

And this not work:

```
def veentanaPrincipal():
    top = Tkinter.Tk()
    var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    def buscarPorNombre():
        pa = Tkinter.Tk()
        L1 = Tkinter.Label(pa, text="Introduzca el nombre"+"\n"+ "completo del remitente:")
        E1 = Tkinter.Entry(pa, textvariable = var)  
        def buscar():
            buscarPorNombreYApellidos(var.get()) 

        B1 = Tkinter.Button(pa, text ="Buscar", command = buscar)
        L1.pack(side = Tkinter.LEFT)
        B1.pack(side = Tkinter.RIGHT)
        E1.pack( side = Tkinter.RIGHT)

    B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Buscar por Nombre y Apellidos", command = buscarPorNombre)    
    B.pack()    
    top.mainloop()
```

Help me please.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you look for some tutorials on how to properly create a Tkinter application, or you'll end up having to keep track of a lot of scopes like this.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Your problem is likely due to where you define `var`, but it's impossible to know because the code you posted has incorrect indentation.

Comment: If it's not working, you are probably getting an error message that is telling you why. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

`var` is local variable so you can't access it in another function.

You can use `global` (or learn "Object Programming")

```
import Tkinter as tk

def buscar():
    global var

    print var.get()

def buscarPorNombre():
    global var

    var = tk.StringVar()
    E1 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=var)  
    E1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    B1 = tk.Button(top, text="OK", command=buscar)
    B1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

top = tk.Tk()
B = tk.Button(top, text="RUN", command=buscarPorNombre)    
B.pack()    
top.mainloop()
```